# "solution" vs. "approach" in academic writing

Tags: vocabulary

I have been trying to understand the differences between solution and approach, as well as when to use which. For instance, what are the differences between the following sentences?

1. Different *solutions* to A can be categorized into two categories.
2. Different *approaches* to A can be classified into two categories.

I have the impression that a *solution* implies a permanent, final, and correct way that provides a definitive answer to a problem. A solution is applicable only for problems where the right answer exists, such as "the solution of a linear equation."

On the other hand, I think an approach is more applicable to scenarios where it is unclear whether it is possible to reach an optimal definitive answer. It needs to be used as an attempt to address some problem without necessarily truly solves the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds reasonable. One is a puzzle metaphor -- there is at least one solution, maybe more, and they solve the puzzle or problem. The other is a motion metaphor -- there is something that one approaches, from various directions, until one reaches it, if one does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you. I add that there are many possible approaches to a problem, whether or not a solution exists.